# Fullscreen API change default color

Tags: html, css, html5-fullscreen

I'm using the [fullscreen api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) and the default color for the border is black as seen in this image:[image]

Image is from http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/full-screen/index2.html.

I would like to change this background color to a different color. Assuming the div has id #content, I've tried using

```
#content::backdrop {
  background-color: red;
}
```

but this did not work for me.

How do I change the color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `:fullscreen` CSS pseudo-class with vendor info. You can see a nice tutorial with an example [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/fullscreen/) and docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API).

I've added the following to [your example](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/full-screen/index2.html) and it worked for me:

```
#myimage:fullscreen {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#myimage:-webkit-full-screen {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#myimage:-moz-full-screen {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#myimage:-ms-fullscreen {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Has this changed at all? Is there one for chrome? I'm using the `*` selector... and having no success.

Comment: Odd enough, it won't change the background color, yet I can control its overflow...